# Laravel or where join

Tags: php, laravel

how can i do "orwhere" "join" in my query?
Help me please thank you

```
$datas =  DB::table("stocks")
          ->where('stocks.code','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('stocks.name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->join('stocksUnits', 'stocksUnits.code', '=', 'stocks.unit') <--- OR WHERE
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$datas =  DB::table("stocks")
          ->where('stocks.code','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('stocks.name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere(static function ($query) {
              $query->join('stocksUnits', 'stocksUnits.code', '=', 'stocks.unit');
          })
          ->get();
```